# Angular routing isn't showing content

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular-routing

I wanted to implement routing in such a way that if you click on the dropdown it goes to that particular page. But i want the header to remain while routing to other components.It is going to the particular url but it isn't showing the content.I have tried child routing but it doesn't seem to work.

[image]

The above picuture is how the dropdown looks like. It has the following url

> localhost:4200/body

when i click on the user management I want it to go to

> localhost:4200/body/user

**Though it goes to the particular url it doesn't show any content below** as in the picture.

[image]

These are my codes (app.routing.ts and .html)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post your code and not image. Please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please create a stackblitz code.

Answer (score 6):

I think you forgot to add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your BodyComponent
html. add it's all of your code seems fine

Answer (score 1):

This is what happened to me:
Since it wasn't working, I tried to see if it gives an error if I remove

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

It didn't. But then I pasted back, and it worked!!!
Could have been a caching problem?!?

Answer (score 1):

For me, I added a route like:

```
{ path: '/', component: HomeComponent }
```

and the browser console threw error

```
Invalid configuration of route '/': path cannot start with a slash
```

So I replaced that with:

```
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

Lesson learnt: **Keep an eye on the Browser console**

Answer (score 0):

Accordinh tonthe [doc](https://angular.io/guide/router)

```
const crisisCenterRoutes: Routes = [   {
    path: 'crisis-center',
    component: CrisisCenterComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: CrisisListComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: ':id',
            component: CrisisDetailComponent
          },
          {
            path: '',
            component: CrisisCenterHomeComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    ]   } ];
```

So for your case you will have :

```
{ path: 'body', component:      BodyComponent, children: [ { path: '', redirectTo: 'user', pathMatch: 'full' }, { path: 'user', component: UserComponent } ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have nested routes you have to have nested router outlet:

```
{ path: 'user', component: LoginViewComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'catalog', component: CatalogViewComponent },
      {
        path: 'home',  component: HomeViewComponent,
      }
    ]
},      
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'user' }
```

Then:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
      <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a routerLinkActive="active" 
          routerLink="/user">Login</a></li>
        <li> <a routerLinkActive="active" 
          routerLink="/user/home">Home</a></li>
        <li> <a routerLinkActive="active" 
          routerLink="/user/catalog">Catalog</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
```

And in your child component:

```
<h1>Login</h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

[I created a working example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-x7nhxk).